# MySQL JOIN query -

Tags: mysql, sql

I know this question has already asked here, but I can't figure this one out from the previous answers.

We've got 2 tables:

```
members
-----------------------
| id | country_iso_3 |
-----------------------
  1    USA
  2    DZA
  3    FRA
  4    ILI
  5    USA
  6    USA


members_details
-----------------------
| member_id | city    |
-----------------------
  1          AA
  2          BB
  3          CC
  4          DD
  5          EE
  6          FF
```

Now I want to query members_details and select the cities which are from the same countries, here "AA", "EE" and "FF" should be the results (because the members are from USA)

I know how to compare different cols from different tables, but here we need to check the second table 'member_id' and the first table 'id (country_iso_3)' somehow!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select city from members LEFT JOIN members_details 
ON members.id = members_details.memberid Where country_iso_3 = 'USA'
```

Answer (score 1):

Just `JOIN` the two tables, with a `WHERE` clause for the country you want to get the city of it like so:

```
SELECT md.city 
FROM members m
INNER JOIN members_details md ON m.id = md.memberid
WHERE m.country_iso_3 = 'USA'
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b8065/3)

Answer (score 0):

This should work, and not only for USA, but for any country which is listed more than once:

```
SELECT d.city
FROM members m,
     members_details d
WHERE d.member_id = m.id
  AND m.country_iso_3 IN (
    SELECT country_iso_3
    FROM members
    GROUP BY 1
    HAVING count(1) > 1
)
```